# Slider doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, slider

i am trying to add a slider to my site. I got it from this site : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/K3Al3 .

I add HTML codes , CSS codes and Javascript codes but slider doesn't work.

Anyone have a idea?

These are the codes :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```
<div id="first-slider">
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="item active slide1">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/pfmmo6qj1/window_domain.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Add images, or even your logo!</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Easily use stunning effects</h4>             
                 </div>
            </div></div>
         </div> 
        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <div class="item slide2">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown"> 50 animation options A beautiful</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Create beautiful slideshows </h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/sp11uneml/rack_server_unlock.png">
                </div>
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item 3 -->
        <div class="item slide3">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Simple Bootstrap Carousel</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Bootstrap Image Carousel Slider with Animate.css</h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/eq8xvxeq5/globe_network.png">
                </div>     
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Item 4 -->
        <div class="item slide4">
            <div class="row"><div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                    <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">We are creative</h3>
                    <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Get start your next awesome project</h4>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                    <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/9vf8xngel/internet_speed.png">
                </div>  
            </div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Item 4 -->

    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper for slides-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
(function( $ ) {

//Function to animate slider captions 
function doAnimations( elems ) {
    //Cache the animationend event in a variable
    var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

    elems.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $animationType = $this.data('animation');
        $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
            $this.removeClass($animationType);
        });
    });
}

//Variables on page load 
var $myCarousel = $('#next'),
    $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

//Initialize carousel 
$myCarousel.carousel();

//Animate captions in first slide on page load 
doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

//Pause carousel  
$myCarousel.carousel('pause');


//Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
$myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
    doAnimations($animatingElems);
});  
$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
    interval:3000,
    pause: "false"
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: I'm assuming you probably forgot to include the JQuery Library as that plugin is using JQuery by what do you get in the console?

Comment: There is no error in browser. I added JQery library. I add an alert to javascript codes it work but slider codes doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I Think jQuery is Missing in your Code. You May Include any jQuery Library before your script.  Use the Below CDN Library and Bootstrap Library.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also Add Bootstrap Library

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.. You are very clever and good person , i was trying to get it right for 2-3 hours... Thank you

Comment: OK. You are Welcome. Thank you. You May Check this.  https://jsfiddle.net/adhershmnair/gn6jxxd7/

Answer (score 0):

Use these headers

```
<!--  headers for https://bootsnipp.com --><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css"><script src="https:////code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script><script src="https:////netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```